# Question About Subtitles In Movies

Tags: video, fonts

i download a 720p Movie like every time i do but the difference that all of them downloaded with subtitles in them no need to download subtitle files except 1 movie needs a subtitles file ,So I downloaded one and ended when i added it by appearing of some strange symbols in the video! how to fix that knowing that the subs are in Arabic .
is That a bug in Ubuntu or what !! does Ubuntu contain Arabic fonts pack? if not how to get them because i am tired of searching.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that you need to add information about.

- What language did you download the subtitle in?
- What video player are you using to play the movie?

Usually the operating system has little to do with what type of font your player outputs. So if your subtitle is in Arabic then your player needs to support that font.

I suggest you re-ask this question on superuser.com and please specify the extra information.

Cheers,
Gergely.

Comment: I downloaded it in arabic, sir and the video player is the one comes with ubuntu 'video'

Comment: In that case please try vlc => http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html It's the most advance and widely used video player out there and supports many languages out of the box. You have to attach the subtitle to the video or name the subtitle the same as the video and it will attached automatically.

Comment: i did Thanks .. Worked but showing some squares in the text :'D

Comment: Look at this video => Might fix your encoding problem. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZQDJ5xd7w8 If it is that. :)